# In a casual top-down racing game, should collisions affect the car's engine?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, racing

Is there a way to deter players from colliding with obstacles in a top-down casual racer which keeping the game fun and lighthearted and yet make player's skill matter?

Should collisions affect car engine performance in a casual racing game? If so, in what way could it be done that keeps it fun?

Please use references (to other games) and examples in your answers.

Comment: If it's top-down, **casual** as you say I think the penalty of having to get back up to speed would be good enough. Just my opinion though, you should playtest. :)

Comment: I don't think there's a *correct* answer here. This is really just polling for ideas and should be asked in chat. It's really just a preference for how you want to make your game.

Comment: @Byte56 - The same could be said about this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/how-do-you-prevent-inflation-in-a-virtual-economy

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite I somewhat agree, we should consider that one next.

Comment: I moved this discussion to meta: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/939/are-questions-abut-popular-game-mechanics-and-gameplay-irrelevant

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite there is a little bit difference between your question and that one which makes me back Byte56. you are asking how people feel and how people like something to be done, while he was asking how did other game (previous professionals) completed that task. your's is kinda endless discussion oriented question while that one only has a few correct answers. IMO the problem is not your question but how you asked it.

Comment: @Gajoo To quote my own question "How is it done in other successful racing games" "Would you offer examples of games that handle this well and one that do it poorly" "...and reference games you.." While he actually never mentioned people should base their answer on other games.

Comment: -1 for being lengthy, rambling, and polling for opinions, as though this was a discussion forum.  "What is the way it is done in your favorite racing game?" is not a useful question in this format.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the meta, I changed the question which was clean because Ricket suggested a link that warmly recommends using and asking for "personal experience"..

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite all I say is that your question need an edit, maybe keep the first sentence and delete the rest, beside the first line and those one or two parts you mentioned yourself, all other parts will be answered based on how people feel and not by the facts.

Comment: Well now it looks like I'm answering a totally different question :/

Comment: You are basically asking people how your design should be. If you have an idea. Try it out and "debug" your gameplay. There really is no point in asking others. You should consider asking yourself "Does it fit with my current design?", "Who is my target audience?". Stuff like this. Ultimately it's your responsibility as a gamedeveloper. Your current question is not so different before your edit. Iterate your gamedesign and do play testing!

Comment: @Sidar, maybe he's asking for ideas, so he can pick one after another, when 'debugging'.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady GDSE is not meant for that. Because there is no right answer. He needs to playtest all of his idea if he wants to know if it fits his design.

Comment: @Sidar Please use the meta for this discussion:
http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/939/are-questions-abut-popular-game-mechanics-and-gameplay-irrelevant
Or read the faq, it clears up the issue: What kind of questions can I ask here? game design (level design, gameplay, mechanics, etc)

Comment: Come on Arthur, you're asking if collision should affect the car engine. It's absolutely subjective. It's something you have to test and see if it fits within your game. There is no right answer to this. The only person who can answer this is you as a gamdeveloper. It's your responsibility. No point in going to Meta.

Comment: This question is not fit for this site, period. It depends entirely on your motives and goals. I suggest closing this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "slow-down from the collision" has always been enough to discourage me from driving carelessly in racing games.  If you hit a wall head-on, you're immediately at a dead stop.  You'll be passed by any cars that were within 10-20 sec of you, depending how many seconds it takes your car to get back up to speed once you're positioned back onto the track.

Also, if you introduce a health bar and the car can become totaled or no longer driveable, it may make the game less playable for children (who crash a lot).

Comment: Seem reasonable, after all if you collide directly you loose 100% speed and then it is a matter of how fast you accelerate back to top speed, these leaves ample room for your enemies to pass you by and get ahead in the race.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, i'm sorry for any gramar erros. English is not my first language. feel free to edit my answer if you find it necessary.

In my oppinion, you have to consider the type of game you are trying to create.

If you are making a game more similar to reality, slowing the speed of the car and and screw it up a bit would make the gameplay more fun and realistic.

But, if you are making a casual game, using a funnier type of penallity, like blowing the car, or making the car spin around, would fit better in the game.

It's worth Remembering Mario kart, when a car sliding off the track, he was brought back by a koopa in a cloud. This kind of penality was great with the language of the game, and no matter if you stay several positions behind, because you could always get some itens and get back to first position.

But this same kind of penality would not work in need for speed, because you would lost too much time, and could not go back to first position.

Always consider the kind of game you are making and try to find a penality that causes the player some problem, but that is not impossible to get over.

Answer (score 4):

I will take part in your survey :)

> What is the way it is done in your favorite racing game?

I prefer when the car is slowed down or stopped and damage is applied to the car. After enough damage, the car's handling or top speed is reduced.

> How is it done in other successful racing games?

I don't play a lot of racing games, but the ones I'm familiar with will cause a slow down + damage. Unless the accident is really bad, then the car will be destroyed on impact.

> Do you think temporarily disabling the engine for a second is too
>   severe?

For a full second? Not if the car can maintain existing momentum. If the car had to stop for a second, then get back up to speed it may be a problem. You'd have to play test it and see what felt right.

> If I do go that route, how would I convey the 'engine is disabled' to
>   the player in a subtle and easily understood way?

You could flash an engine icon at the top of the screen and/or play sounds of a sputtering engine. Or sounds of an engine revving up out of gear.

> Is this 'too much' of a penalty?

You can change the time of the delay based on the severity of the impact. So players will know that a severe penalty was their own fault.

> Would the slow-down from the collision be sufficient to discourage the
>   player from driving too carelessly?

I guess that depends on the player. If the slowdown was significant enough, they wouldn't drive carelessly any more. But if it's too much, they might not play anymore.

> Which one is more fun?

Blowing up the car when it takes too much damage is typically rated 3 funs above just slowing the car down.

> Should I consider a health-bar and affect engine performance for 'low
>   health' status?

Since you don't mention if the racing game is realistic or cartoony, I'll assume cartoony. Yes, have a health bar. The engine should slow down and make coughing noises when it's very damaged.

> Could you offer examples of games that handle this well and one that
>   do it poorly?

I don't remember the specific names of the games, but I know there was one racing game where when you hit something and slowed down, the AI racers were always *right behind you* to overtake you. No matter how much of a lead you had on them. Don't do it that way.

> Please share your experience with racing games obstacles and reference
>   games you feel perform well in this aspect.

Again, I don't remember the specific names. But there was one that would just slow you down and have realistic body damage to the vehicle when the car was hit.

> I would also like to hear how you feel we should penalize or reward
>   for colliding with other vehicles?

Same deal, cars should be damaged based on the severity of the crash. For example a head on collision would be devastating, but a side swipe would be barely anything.

> Should enemy vehicles be destroyable? Should they slow down severely
>   when they hit the back of your car or would that make the gameplay
>   imbalanced?

Yes! Take them out of the race. Enemy vehicles should have all the same penalties as your car. You should be able to side swipe them to make the crash into other cars or trees.

Comment: lol survey. I was going to say not really an answer, but you answered all the questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Slow down is important for physics simulation.
Especially if there are more then 2 colliding objects.

At high speed most racing games handle collision in non-physics way otherwise car angular velocity was too high. They ignore